# SustainSys.Saml2 on ASP.NET Core 2 - GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() returns null

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, sustainsys-saml2, gluu

I'm integrating SustainSys.Saml2, with Gluu server as my IdP. I'm using the scaffolded Identity pages out of the box. When I run in localhost, and I view the console log everything seems to work with the SAML communication, and I even see a couple lines that read:

```
Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Handler[0]
Successfully processed SAML response Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Id and authenticated
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[10]
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed in.
```

Unless I'm mistaken, that indicates everything's good on the SAML end of things. But what I don't then understand is why, in `ExternalLogin.OnGetCallbackAsync`, the command

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

finds `info` set to `null`.

For the record, in Startup.cs, I have:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
  .AddSaml2(options =>
  {
    options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("{entityId}");
    options.IdentityProviders.Add(
      new IdentityProvider(new EntityId("{entityId}"), options.SPOptions)
      {
        Metadatalocation = "{metadataURL}",
      });
    options.Validate();
  });
```

Comment: Yes, you are right that the SAML end succeeded. Looks like the identity.external cookie is also correctly set (verify in browser dev tools). Then for some reason `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` doesn't pick up the identity from the cookie.

Comment: @AndersAbel I do not have an identity.external cookie. Can you think of a reason why it would be missing?

Comment: @AndersAbel Also, I'm told by the Gluu customer support (forums) that "response type" should be "code id_token", but in my DevTools network log, the only response type I see is "code", without "id_token" being specified. I don't see a place in the API to specify that. Do you know if it is (or is not) possible?

Comment: @David were you ever able to figure this out? I'm facing almost the exact same issue. The SAMLResponse is processed - and says it's authenticated - but the resulting user session has no claims.

Comment: @AndersAbel do you have any ideas on this? I had also created a question here before seeing this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61313491/how-to-retrieve-claims-from-idp-initiated-login-using-sustainsys-saml2

Comment: @ChiefMcFrank Sorry, Chief. This remains unresolved. I've just been working on other tasks since then and haven't circled back. Please let me know if you get it; I'll still need it!

Comment: Ah dang! That's sad, but thanks for replying. Will do!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to figure this out based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/issues/1030), and Anders' notes in there.

I'll link to my comment there. Read Anders' comment above that for explanation. https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/issues/1030#issuecomment-616842796